# Disposing a hidden form

Tags: .net, winforms, garbage-collection, parent-child

I have a question about closing and disposing a hidden child form.

Parent form with two buttons:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim F2 As Form2

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        F2 = New Form2
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        F2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        F2.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Child form:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
            e.Cancel = True
            Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.VisibleChanged
        MsgBox("Form2.Visible = " & Me.Visible.ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Disposed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
        MsgBox("Form2 has been disposed.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

As long as Form1 is open, I don't want to close Form2. So that part works.
But I do want to close Form2 when Form1 is closed. Do I have to close it explicitly from Form1? And add more logic to Form2_FormClosing()?
As is, Form2_Disposed() never gets called as far as I can tell (I never get the message box). Is this correct?
When Form1 is disposed, variable F2 no longer exists. Will the Form2 be disposed by the garbage collector later on or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to move the Form2_FormClosing event to the Form1 class.
In this way you will be able to control the closing of the Form2 instance from the Form1 instance.

```
' global instance flag
Dim globalCloseFlag As Boolean = False

...
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
    F2 = New Form2  
    AddHandler F2.FormClosing, New FormClosingEventHandler(AddressOf Form2ClosingHandler)
End Sub  

' This will get the event inside the form1 instance, you can control the close of F2 from here
Private Sub Form2ClosingHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) 
    if globalCloseFlag = false then    
        e.Cancel = True    
        F2.Hide()
    end if

End Sub 

' Form1 closing, call the close of F2
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing      
      globalCloseFlag = True
      F2.Close()
End Sub
```

Please, pay attention that this is an example, you need to handle special cases like windows shutdown using the FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason property

Comment: Hmm, `F2.FormClosing = New FormClosingEventHandler(AddressOf Form2ClosingHandler)` produced an error:

`'Public Event FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.`

Comment: Thanks Steve. Just one more thing. Inside `Form2ClosingHandler()`, it should be `F2.Hide()` instead of `Me.Hide()`. Otherwise it hides Form1, making both forms impossible to close. :)

Comment: So what happens if we don't explicitly close F2 when we close Form1? Do we get an unreachable, unreferenced instance of Form2 that never gets disposed or destroyed by the garbage collector?

Comment: Yeah, copy/paste. About the garbage collector. When closing Form1 the code above call F2.Close. At this point you could also add `F2.Dispose();` and `F2 = null;` (provided there is no more use of that var in next events), but you gain little to none benefit. The Garbage collector knows when an object is no more referenced and clears the remaining bit itself. There are methods to force the Garbage Collector to clean immediately, but there are strong advices to not use them.

Comment: I was wondering what happens if we don't handle Form1 closing events at all, and do nothing to close/dispose F2. We simply close Form1. Will the Form2 be disposed/destroyed implicitly by the garbage collector or not?

Comment: Has I have said, the garbage collector keep track of every NET object. When an object is no more referenced it becomes eligible to be garbage collected when the system decides. I suppose that when Form1 close it will be collected and then the F2 is no more referenced. I'm not sure if the collection of the two objects is simultaneous, but I'm sure the two objects are destroyed.

Comment: Then is there any benefit in closing F2 explicitly? Form2 is just a simple form; all I care about is disposing/destroying it after Form1 closes, it doesn't have to be simultaneous I don't think. Or is this a bad programming style?